# AdvanceDataGrid column field to allow entering text/editing with just one click instead of 2.

Tags: apache-flex

I am new to flex. I hav an advance datagrid column with an Item Editor. When I click on the column,the editor on the column gets enabled after clicking twice instead of one time. 
         What can be done so that the editor can be be enabled with a single click.

TIA

Comment: Have you property doubleClickEnabled = true?

Comment: This doesn't sound like the standard behaviour. If you can reproduce it in a small application, then edit your question and add that code, maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

See this example, the editor activates after a single click:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955"       minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:ArrayList id="dataGridData">
            <fx:Object name="Bob" definition="stuff"/>
            <fx:Object name="Joe" definition="stuff"/>
            <fx:Object name="Tim" definition="stuff"/>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </fx:Declarations>

<mx:AdvancedDataGrid dataProvider="{dataGridData}" editable="true">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn id="colName" headerText="a" editable="true" dataField="name"/>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn id="colDefinition" headerText="b" editable="true" dataField="definition"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: My question will be clarified with the below code snippet :
  
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid dataProvider="{dataGridData}" editable="true">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn id="colName" headerText="a" itemEditor="{new ClassFactory(CustomItemEditorForSomeValidation)}" dataField="name"/>
           </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
</s:Application>

Now if I have to edit data for AdvancedDataGridColumn id="colName", i need to double-click the column. But my requirement is to enable editing with single click. Hope I am clear with the question now. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: There's probably a problem with your CustomItemEditorForSomeValidation, can I see the code for that as well?